# Scoring in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `constant_score` query with filter but need a lower score if all the condition of filter in `constant_score` are matching but also an additional check is passing

Index looks like this

```
{
"mappings": {
 "properties": {
   "name": {
     "type": "text"
   },
   "expiry" : {
     "type": "nested"
   }
 }
}
}
```

Sample document is:

```
{
  "name": "Awesome",
  "expiry": [
    {
      "batchNo": 1,
      "expiryInDays": 10
    },
    {
      "batchNo": 2,
      "expiryInDays": 20
    },
    {
      "batchNo": 3,
      "expiryInDays": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Constant score query is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name": "awesome"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "expiry",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "expiry.batchNo": 3
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Looking to create query which can score the record with `expiry.expiryInDays = 0 along with the condition in filter` with lower score than only with `filter condition`

Comment: I don't understand correctly, do you want all doc "name": "awesome" and "expiry.batchNo": 3 to have a score less than 1? So your boot constant_score should be less than 1. Read the documentation that says: Wraps a filter query and returns every matching document with a relevance score equal to the boost parameter value.

Comment: I want to get the constant score for every doc with name:awesome and batchNo: 3 if the expiryInDays > 0 but if expiryInDays <=0 I want to give a lower score to that match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant score query can be wrapped in should clause to get two set of scores.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "awesome"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "expiry",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "expiry.batchNo": 3
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "expiry",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "expiry.batchNo": 3
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "expiry.expiryInDays": {
                            "gt": 0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "expiry",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "expiry.batchNo": 3
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "expiry.expiryInDays": {
                            "lte": 0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZGQcZIIBcSdWVUHM9rQD",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Awesome",
          "expiry" : [
            {
              "batchNo" : 1,
              "expiryInDays" : 10
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 2,
              "expiryInDays" : 20
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 3,
              "expiryInDays" : 5
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "YmQcZIIBcSdWVUHMurTD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Awesome",
          "expiry" : [
            {
              "batchNo" : 1,
              "expiryInDays" : 10
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 2,
              "expiryInDays" : 20
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 3,
              "expiryInDays" : 0
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZWQ4ZIIBcSdWVUHMcrRa",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Awesome",
          "expiry" : [
            {
              "batchNo" : 1,
              "expiryInDays" : 10
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 2,
              "expiryInDays" : 20
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 3,
              "expiryInDays" : 0
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ZmQ4ZIIBcSdWVUHMkLQ-",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Awesome",
          "expiry" : [
            {
              "batchNo" : 1,
              "expiryInDays" : 10
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 2,
              "expiryInDays" : 50
            },
            {
              "batchNo" : 3,
              "expiryInDays" : 0
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```